# Graphing Polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation, polynomial-math

I need to create a polynomial of the form:

P(x) = q(1,1) + q(2,2)(x-z(1)) + q(3,3)(x-z(1))(x-z(2)) + --- + q(2n, 2n)(x-z(1))(x-z(2))...(x-z(2n)) **NOTE: The indices of the equation have been shifted to accomodate MATLAB.**

in MATLAB. [Consult this link here specifically slides 15 and 16.](http://personal.psu.edu/jjb23/web/html/sl455SP12/ch3/CH03_4B.pdf)

I have the matrix Q filled, so I have the diagonal, and I also have z(1:2n) filled.

I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to create a polynomial that I can graph this polynomial. I've tried to use a for loop to append each term to P(x), but it doesn't operate the way I thought it would.

So far, my code will calculate the coefficients (presented as Q(0,0) -> Q(2n+1, 2n+1) in the problem above) without a problem.

I'm having an issue with the construction of a degree n polynomial of the form described above. Plotting makes more sense now, create a vector x with evaluative values, and then run them through the polynomial "function" and plot the x vector against the resulting vector.

So I just need to create this polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `diag` and `cumprod` to help you accomplish this.  First use `diag` to extract the diagonals of your matrix `Q`.  After, use `cumprod` to generate a vector of cumulative products.

How `cumprod` works on a vector is that for each element in the vector, the i'th element collects products from 1 up to the i'th element.  As an example, if we had a vector `V = [1 2 3 4 5]`, `cumprod(V)` would produce `[1 2 6 24 120]`.  The 4th element (as an example) would be `1*2*3*4`, representing the products from the 1st to the 4th element.

As such, this is the code that I would do:

```
qdiag = diag(Q);
xMinusZ = x - z; % Takes z and does x - z for every element in z
cumProdRes = cumprod(xMinusZ);
P = sum(qdiag .* [1;cumProdRes(1:end-1)]);
```

`P` should give you `P(x)` that you desired.  Make sure that `z` is a column vector to make it compatible with the diagonals extracted from `Q`.

**NB:** I believe there is a typo in your equation.  The last term of your equation (going with your convention) should have `(x-z(2n-1))` and not `(x-z(2n))`.  This is because the first term in your equation does not have `z`.

Here's an example.  Let's suppose `Q` is defined

```
Q = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16];
```

The vector `z` is:

```
z = [4;3;2;1];
```

Let's evaluate the function at `x = 2`

Extracting the diagonals of `Q` should give us `Q = [1;6;11;16]`.  Subtract `x` from every element of `z` should give us:

```
xMinusZ = [-2;-1;0;1];
```

Using the equation that you have above, we have:

```
P = 1 + 6*(-2) + 11*(-2)*(-1) + 16*(-2)*(-1)*(0) = 11
```

This is what the code should give.

### What if we want to do this for more than one value of x?

As you have stated in your post, you want to evaluate this for a series of `x` values.  As such, you need to modify the code so that it looks like this (make sure that `x` is a column vector):

```
qdiag = diag(Q);
xMinusZ = repmat(x,1,length(z)) - repmat(z',length(z),1);
cumProdRes = cumprod(xMinusZ,2);
P = sum(repmat(qdiag',length(z),1).*[ones(length(z),1) cumProdRes(:,1:end-1)],2);
```

`P` should now give you a vector of outputs, and so if you want to plot this, simply do `plot(x,P);`

Comment: I've run into a whole mess of problems with indexing. The problem as presented to me uses [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4], so they iterate from 0 to n, where n would be 4. My MATLAB implementation uses 1-based indexing, so I go from [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5] and my n = 5. The psuedo-code uses Q(0,0) to Q(2n+1,2n+1), which in those eyes would be 0 to 9, where I use 1 to 10, so 2n.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you put in the unaltered equation so I can translate it myself.  Put the one in that has an offset at 0 instead of 1.  That way there is no ambiguity.  Please edit your post to reflect that and I will edit my code.

Comment: It's not really much of an index problem anymore, more of a, how do I create this degree n polynomial.

Comment: Alright. Well I see you've accepted my answer. Glad I could help!

Comment: Had to play with the 2nd and 4th line of your bottom selection to get proper matrix dimensions, but I went through iteratively and got a full understanding of your method.